# Save data from listview to mysql database with vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here's my trial for saving messages from listview to database, with gsm modem.
I try to make sending and receiving sms windows application.

**Code to save messages:**

```
Private Sub btnSaveMessage_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveMessage.Click
    Try
        Connection()
        query = "INSERT INTO tblInbox(index, status, number, date, message) VALUES('" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(2).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(3).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(4).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(5).Text & "')"
        sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader

        MsgBox("Message Save")
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Connection code**

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module db_connection
    Public sqlreader As MySqlDataReader
    Public sqlcmd As MySqlCommand
    Public sqladapter As MySqlDataAdapter

    Public conn As New MySqlConnection

    Public Sub Connection()
        Try
            conn = New MySqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; userid=root; password=root; database=thesis"
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, status, number, data, message) VALUES('0', 'REC READ', '+63907231323',' at line 1

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong, where and what to do.  If you refer to [9.3 MySql Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) you'll see `Index` is a reserved word

Comment: (so is Date, Status and Data)  fire your db designer and dont concat SQL

Comment: I see, thank you so much sir. I will change it later, I am currently surfing at internet cafe.